# Unity Interceptor Support at Design-Time

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

How can I "translate" this Unity Fluent API code into XML Design-Time?

```
container.RegisterType<IRat, Rat>().Configure<Interception()
  .SetInterceptorFor<IRat>(new InterfaceInterceptor());
```

I tried the code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648172.aspx) but it seems to be outdated, since I am working with the last version of Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do interception with an IInterceptionBehavior the configuration would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>

  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <assembly name="MyApp"/>
    <namespace name="MyApp"/>
    <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration" />

    <container>
      <extension type="Interception"/>
      <register type="MyInterceptor">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
      </register>
      <register type="IRat" mapTo="Rat">
        <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
        <interceptionBehavior type="MyInterceptor"/>
      </register>
    </container>
  </unity>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

You need to declare a sectionExtension and then add the Interception extension to the container.  Then when registering types supply the interceptor and interceptionBehavior.  If using call handlers then you would add the PolicyInjection behavior.

Comment: Do people not use the fluent configuration? I feel like I might be missing a trick by configuring my container in code. I could possibly be extending my application without a rebuild by dropping in new assemblies and updating the configuration.

Comment: Yes, declarative (XML) config is used.  I prefer programmatic configuration  (and I think it's more common) but if you may want to change how an application is wired up (and it's fairly complicated) without recompilation it might make sense.  In my app, I have a similar interception behavior to the above answer but I control whether it is applied by a single AppSettings config item without using Unity XML Configuration.